# When unchecking VERP option I am getting an error "Boolean value required for track_civimail_replies"

Tags: civimail

When I go to Administer > CiviMail > CiviMail Component Settings. There is an option
"Track replies using VERP in Reply-To header"

When I uncheck this box and hit Save I am getting an error message
"Boolean value required for track_civimail_replies"
Does anyone know what this means and how I can successfully turn of VERP?

I am using CiviCRM 5.36.1
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not similar, but related issue is already logged on gitlab issue. [enter link description here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2461) and has been [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19805) and will be available on 5.37 release.

You can either wait for 5.37 release or apply [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19805.patch).

Alternatively you can add below line in civicrm.settings.php to turn off VERP setting.

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['track_civimail_replies'] = FALSE;
```